# Knex.js (PostgreSQL): return from count from update only when data change

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, knex.js

I want to update a column and get count greater than 0 from `.update()` method only when data is really changes, so i can track if update is done. currently i've get always `1` also when the value in DB is the same as the desired updated value.

My current code is:

```
const updatedRowsCount = await getKnexWithSchema<JobTableColumns, JobTableColumns[]>(trx)
  .from(JOBS_TABLE)
  .whereIn('uuid', uuids)
  .whereNotIn('status', [JobStatus.SUCCESS, JobStatus.ABORTED, JobStatus.FAILED])
  .where(convertJobTypeToDB(where || {}))
  .update(convertJobTypeToDB(updatedData));
```

There is any way to achieve that? read the Knex.js doc and didn't find.

Comment: Would this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41618078/2805154

Comment: not looks like, but thx, i'll keep searching.

Comment: I think the challenge is that if you update a record but the new value is the same as the old then SQL sees the number of records updated as 1 because it actually touched that record. You'd have to only update the record if the new value was different to change that.

Comment: So one more select before update is needed?

Comment: You could add `.whereNot()` clauses to your update to filter out the record that already has the new value.